# word macro join text fields

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document macro enabled, I have a drop down button within the document which takes information from one form field and places it into another form field.

```
Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("Dropdown1").Result
  Case "Order"
    ActiveDocument.FormFields("ord1").Result ActiveDocument.FormFields("p1").Result
End Select
```

How can I adjust the code so that, instead of replacing everything in field "ord1" it would join the existing text within the field?

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like this:

```
 ActiveDocument.FormFields("ord1").Result = _
      ActiveDocument.FormFields("ord1").Result & " " & _
      ActiveDocument.FormFields("p1").Result
```